# Homeomorphic image of graph of continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

let $D\subset (-1,1)\times \Bbb R$ be closed set such it meets each continuous function g on $[-1,1],$ that is, $g\cap D\neq \emptyset$, $g$ means the graph of $g$.  I think it is true that  there is  a homeomorphic  say $H$, $$H\colon (-1,1)\times \Bbb R\to (2,3)\times\Bbb R$$ such that $H[D]$ still has the same properties, that is, it is closed and $H[D]\cap g\neq\emptyset$ for any continuous function $g\colon [2,3]\to \Bbb R.$

Clearly, $H[D]$ is closed but I did not see till this moment if $H[D]$ can intersect each continuous function on $[2,3].$

Comment: "$g$ as graph of $g$ no different" is not a coherent English phrase. Can you rephrase it so it's comprehensible?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I fixed

Comment: Brian M.Scott, I am not sure if you saw my question this why I mentioned you here. Do you have an idea.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Is it correct now ?

Comment: If you just take $H$ to be linear from $(-1,1)$ to $(2,3)$, doesn't that work?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I assumed $H$ to be homeomorphism to make the properties for $D$ they will be preserved but I did not see it till now how this can be done . do you have any idea ?

Comment: I just gave you my idea. Let $H(r,s)=(g(r),s)$ where $g:(-1,1)\to(2,3)$ is linear. See whether it works.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I actually have the same function but I could not how $H[D]$ will intersect each continuous function on $[2,3]$

Comment: Take a continuous function on $[2,3]$. Make a linear change of variable to get a continuous function on $[-1,1]$. Apply the property of $D$ to find an intersection. Then undo the linear change of variable to get an intersection with $H$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Thank you for your idea. Could you just please clear the idea of change the variable since I spent a lot of time without getting nothing. Just even a short answer this would help me a lot.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous on $[2,3]$ then $h=f\circ p$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$, where $p$ is any continuous function from $[-1,1]$ to $[2,3]$. Simplest is to take $p$ to be linear.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, by lineat you meant any linear like $p(x)=ax+b$.right ?

Comment: Does it matter, what I mean? Why don't you just try it, and see what happens?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, okay, since $h\colon [-1,1]\to \Bbb R$ continuous function based in our assumption, $h\cap D\neq\emptyset $, that is,  there is $(r,s)$such that $(r,s)\in h$ and $(r,s)\in D$. Now, $(g(r),s)\in H[D]$ and $s=f(p(r))$. still did not give common point in $H[D]\cap f.$

Comment: @GerryMyerson, How I will ensure point in the intersection ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer  is very simply. @Gerr Myerson gave a hint for the homeomorphisn and I had the same idea before as well but I took me time to check it. Take $$H\colon (-1,1)\times\Bbb R\to (2,3)\times\Bbb R,$$ define by
$$H(x,y)=(g(x),y),$$ where $g\colon (-1,1)\to(2,3)$ be a homeomorphism. Our aim to show $H[D]=\{(g(x),y)\colon (x,y)\in D\}$ intersects each continuous $f\colon [2,3]\to\Bbb R.$ Fix a continuous function $f\colon (2,3) \to \Bbb R.$
Notice that $f\circ g\colon (-1,1)\to \Bbb R$ is a continuous function. So, by our assumption, $$(f\circ g)\cap D\neq\emptyset,$$  that is, there is $(x,y)\in D$ such that $(x,y)\in f\circ g.$ This means $$y=(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x)),$$ which implies to $(g(x),f(g(x))\in f$ and then $(g(x),y)\in f.$ But $(g(x),y)\in H[D]$ since $(x,y)\in D$. Thus, $$H[D]\cap f\neq\emptyset$$ Could you check my short argument?

Comment: Gerr Myerson, I think , it works now, right